# Consecutive fourths in melodic motion

Tags: theory, voice-leading

**Context**:  My theory book is elaborating on some rules for melodic motion to be applied to the soprano voice when *Writing in Four Parts*.

---

In the screenshot below, I'm trying to digest the quote:

*Two leaps of 4ths are usually poor, but arpeggiation of a dominant 7th can be effective*.

---

**Question:** Are these two statements intended to be read in contrast to one another?  I'm trying to imagine a scenario where a dominant 7th chord could be arpeggiated by two consecutive leaps of a 4th, but can't see it happening.

Maybe these are simply two independent rules which are joined with the word "but"?  I'm just seeking clarification on which interpretation is correct.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

The two rules are meant to contrast each other. Two consecutive leaps of a (perfect) 4th combine to span a minor 7th--the same 7th interval as the one a dominant 7th chord uses.

An example of two consecutive leaps of a (perfect) 4th:
F - Bb - Eb

An example of dominant 7th arpeggiation:
F - A - C - Eb

Note how both examples begin and end with the same notes.

My experience is that two consecutive leaps of a perfect fourth sound dangerously close to a tuning exercise, and three such consecutive leaps sound even closer.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, there are only two ways to have two leaps in the same direction that span a 7th: two ascending fourths or a combination of a fifth and third.

In traditional part writing, two consecutive leaps of a fourth will sound out of place because they don't form a chord. Consecutive leaps of a third and a fifth (or a fifth and a third) can be effective in certain cases, most often outlining the dominant 7th chord. Remember that the dominant chord has a special place harmonically as the chord of highest tension, so it can be made to stand out more than other chords.